# Python grouping by and aggregating multiple columns with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to group by multiple column and aggregate on multiple as well.
In sql it would give that:

```
SELECT A, B, C, COUNT(1), SUM(E), SUM(F) GROUP BY A, B, C
```

So far i came up with this but it only aggregate on one column:

```
df.groupby(['A','B','C')['E'].sum()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
print (df.groupby(['A','B','C']).agg({'A':'size', 'E':'sum','F':'sum'}))
```